# how can I run this code as a webpage in python-apache-ubuntu server?

Tags: python, ubuntu, apache2, mod-python

This code snippet works in a normal python interpreter, just a simple binary search. What do I need to add/change to this code to run it as a webpage ?

```
def binarySearch(s,array):
first=0;
last=len(array);
midpoint=first+(last-first)/2;
midpoint=int(midpoint);
#print(midpoint);
print (first,last,array[midpoint]);
if array[midpoint]==s: return (first,last,array[midpoint]);
while midpoint>1:
    if s>array[midpoint]:
        first=midpoint;
        print (first,last,array[midpoint]);
    elif s<array[midpoint]:
        last=midpoint;
        print (first,last,array[midpoint]);
    elif s==array[midpoint]:
        return (first,last,array[midpoint]);
    midpoint=first+(last-first)/2;
    midpoint=int(midpoint);
    #print(midpoint);

return None;

dArray=range(300);

print(binarySearch(90,dArray));
```

Comment: This code raises an `IndentationError`. And even if you fix that, it prints out a whole bunch of irrelevant stuff and then prints out `None`  at the end instead of the expected answer. So that's a strange definition of "works".

Comment: Also, don't put semicolons at the end of lines in Python. And, more generally, take a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Anyway, what do you want "run it as a webpage" to mean? You just want the same text it prints to appear in the browser any time someone accesses a particular URL?

Comment: Finally, you've tagged this `mod-python`. Does that mean that it needs to be a `mod_python` script? If so, why that instead of, say, a simple CGI, or a WSGI, or a Flask app? This implies that you already know enough about `mod_python` to make such a decision, but if you know that much, you should already know how to answer this question (or at least get most of the way and then tell us where you're stuck). Have you even read [the tutorial](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/tutorial.html) for it?

Comment: I could have written print ("Hello World!);, but what is required to run a python script in a the apache server? About the mod-python part; isnt apache using mod-python to run the python scripts in the webserver ? Basically the code needs to be altered to make it run in a webserver, thats the part I am looking for.

Comment: `mod_python` is one of many ways to run scripts in a webserver. CGI, WSGI, frameworks like Flask or Django, etc. are other ways. It's neither the simplest nor necessarily the best.

Answer (score 0):

"Altered to make it run in a webserver" doesn't really mean anything in this case. Your code (well, you have to fix it so it actually runs instead of raising exceptions, but let's pretend you did that) will already just work as a CGI or `mod_python` script. Everything that you `print` (or otherwise write to stdout) will become the response that a browser sees.

You may need to add a `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or similar to the top of your program—just as you'd need to if you want to run it with `./hello.py` in the shell instead of `python3 hello.py`. Then, it's just a matter of configuring your server. If you configure Apache to allow CGI in the `/cgi-bin/` directory, and copy your script to that directory with mode 755, anyone who browses to `http://myserver.example.com/cgi-bin/hello.py` will get back the text `Hello, world!`. If you configure Apache to run `.py` scripts with `mod_python` instead of as CGIs, now you'll see the exact same thing, except maybe slightly faster or with slightly less load on your server.

Comment: I have been checking to write the code with python, my confusion was thinking python is a php like web scripting tool. For example writing print ("Hello World!") is very simple in the python3 interpreter, but making it type the same thing on the web; requires many other scripting to include. What I understand is; as you said earlier; I had to use a framework. Then I can write the code much more simpler for the web by using one of these frameworks. I dont know which one is mostly recommended nowadays, but I seen that DJANGO is more used on the web. Is that right ?

Comment: @user2653865: You _can_ use Python as a PHP-like web-scripting tool. CGI works the same way for either, and `mod_python` works very much like the built-in or `mod_php` interpreter. It's usually not the way you want to do things, because you're right, the frameworks make things a whole lot simpler. (In fact, most PHP sites nowadays use frameworks too.)

Comment: @user2653865: Meanwhile, Django is very popular, but it's also a very big framework, which has a lot of its own idioms that you have to learn. Some people prefer to use lighter-weight frameworks like Flask or Webapp2. Other people like to use something lower-level like Twisted and a bunch of building blocks that you have to put together yourself on top of it. It's hard to say which one is best; it's different for each person, and even for the same person may be different for different sites.